# How to make a installer program in USB flash drive?

Tags: c++, c, windows, qt, cross-platform

Hallo,
I have created a program using C/C++ programming and Qt. Then I would like to make it installable from a USB flash drive. Meaning that once the user plug-in the USB flash drive, the Windows installer wizard will automatically launch. May I know how this can be done? Does it require programming as well or just a deployment software will do?

THanks @!

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple. You just need an autorun.inf file in the root of the usb drive. For information on the autorun format take a look [here](http://www.phdcc.com/shellrun/autorun.htm)

Comment: IIRC, Microsoft are disabling autorun (through Windows update) for everything except optical disks, because it has so often been exploited by malware. Lots of people already have it disabled for the same reason, or just because it's annoying. Don't know for sure, but I'm guessing some features of autorun.inf (such as custom drive icons) will still work, but the feature that gave the file its name will be disabled.

Comment: You are right @Steve314 ([link](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/advisory/967940.mspx)), but I believe the only part being disabled is the actual autorun, so stuff like handling clicks from my computer would still work... I still get the autorun dialog asking me what I want to do on a fully upgraded system, and autorun.inf can add entries in there. It's not a perfect solution but I don't see any alternative.

Comment: I guess that's about right. IMO, autorun is both pointless and evil. I don't see what's so hard about finding and running setup.exe. But then I have plenty of relatives, of course, who don't understand what the hell I'm talking about when I try to explain. "But", they say, "if I get a virus it doesn't matter - you can fix it for me again. It's like all that rubbish about backups - why should I waste five minutes running a backup program you bought for me when it only takes you a week to recover my files and reinstall everything on my PC?".

Comment: @Steve314, that's why I would always choose to use a cd to make an installer. People with little knowledge or computers do know how to put a cd in the drive and go through an installer, it's the standard way of doing things. In any case, it's not possible for security reasons to autorun something from rewritable media, unless you have a service installed listening for it like the iPods use.